# PHP, reload the page and display Invalid credentials message?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this snippet in my index.php file, it will ask a user to log on. If the details aren't in the database system, I want to reload the index.php page and show a message like "Invalid credentials, try again" or something like that.

How can I achieve this? Here is my code:

```
    <?php
session_start();

//Check if user is already logged in
if(!isset($_POST['id']))
{
    $message = 'User is logged in already';
}

//Check the username and password have been submitted
if(!isset( $_POST['Username'], $_POST['Password']))
{
    $message = 'Please enter a valid username and password';
}

//Check the username is the correct length
else if (strlen($_POST['Username']) > 20 || strlen($_POST['Username']) < 4)
{
    $message = 'Incorrect Username length, please try again';
}

//Check the password is the correct length
else if (strlen($_POST['Password']) > 20 || strlen($_POST['Password']) < 4)
{
    $message = 'Incorrect Password length, please try again';
}

//Check the username only has alpha numeric characters
else if (ctype_alnum($_POST['Username']) != true)
{
    $message = "Username must be alpha numeric";
}

else if (ctype_alnum($_POST['Password']) != true)
{
    $message = "Password must be alpha numeric";
}
else
{
    $admin = "****";
    $adminPassword = "****";

    //Enter the valid data into the database
    $username = filter_var($_POST['Username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $password = filter_var($_POST['Password'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    //Encrypt the password
    $password = sha1($password);

    //Connect to the database
    $SQLusername = "";
    $SQLpassword = "";
    $SQLhostname = ""; 
    $databaseName = "";

    try
    {
        //connection to the database
        $dbhandle = mysql_connect($SQLhostname, $SQLusername, $SQLpassword) 
          or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
        echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";

        //select a database to work with
        $selected = mysql_select_db($databaseName, $dbhandle)
                or die("Could not select database");

        $selectCustomers = "SELECT * FROM
                customers WHERE name = 
                '$username' AND password = '$password'";

        $selectEmployees = "SELECT * FROM
                employees WHERE name = 
                '$username' AND password = '$password'";

        $selectAdmin = "SELECT * FROM
                employees WHERE name = 
                '$admin' AND password = '$adminPassword'";

        $customerResult = mysql_query($selectCustomers) or die(mysql_error());
        $employeeResult = mysql_query($selectEmployees) or die(mysql_error());
        $adminResult = mysql_query($selectAdmin) or die(mysql_error());

        if(mysql_num_rows($customerResult) >= 1)
        {
            header("Location: memberPage.php");
            $_SESSION["customer"] = "customer";
        }

        else if(mysql_num_rows($employeeResult) >= 1)
        {
           header("Location: adminPage.php");
           $_SESSION["admin"] = "admin";
        }

        else if(mysql_num_rows($adminResult) >= 1)
        {
           header("Location: adminPage.php");
           $_SESSION["admin"] = "admin";
        }

        else
        {
             header("Location: index.php");
        }

        //close the connection
        mysql_close($dbhandle);
    } 
    catch(Exception $e)
    {

        $message = 'We are unable to process your request. Please try again later"';
    }


}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please past more code? I think you've done a query before.

Comment: so what is the error showing..or which block is executing..?
You can simply echo "invalid credentials..." BUT then header may not work.

Comment: Sure, I've copied my entire index.php file now

Comment: @Riad at the moment, it only reloads the page, but doesn't give a reason as to why the page was reloaded

Comment: Edited, don't paste here you mysql credentials. 
Ps. answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last `else`:

```
else
    {
         header("Location: index.php");
         //I would like to return a message here and then reload this page
    }
```

Try to change it with:

```
else
    {
die(header('refresh: 3; url=index.php').'Invalid Credentials, wait 3 seconds or just click <a href="index.php">HERE</a> to check again.');
    }
```

Where **"3"** is number of seconds to wait for the refresh (reload the page).

Hope this could help you!

Comment: This is great, thanks very much for your help :) I have to wait 5 minutes before I can accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("invalid credentials");</script>' ;
echo '<script type="text/javascript">location.reload();</script>' ;
```

Comment: yep, it's right also this, but for this type of things it's better a total server-side configuration, however User2757842, you can use also this in the "**else**" i mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can try giving the parameters like :

```html
header("Location: index.php?err=1");
```

and then getting the error into the page by

```html
if($_GET['err']==1)
{

echo "your credentials are wrong";

}
```

Hope this helps...